# Ranking positions using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

Trying to rank positions but instead of giving (1,2,3,3,5..) when there is a tie in the 3rd position it gives (1,2,3,4,5...).. Help please
below is the code.. thanks
.............................................................................

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT @curRank := IF(@prev= @cur, @curRank, @curRank + 1 ) AS classPosition,student_id, @prev:=@cur, @cur:=SUM(total_marks)
      FROM (SELECT m.*
            FROM marks m
            WHERE classform_name = ? AND term = ? AND academic_year = ? GROUP BY student_id
            ORDER BY SUM(total_marks) DESC
           ) n  CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT  @curRank := 0, @prev:=NULL, @cur:=NULL ) q GROUP BY student_id
     ) t 
WHERE student_id = ?
```

.............................................................................

Comment: Sample data is a big help.

Comment: What version of mysql are you using -- some versions have the RANK window function

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a RANK function.  You can always rank rows by [joining the table to itself](http://www.schemamania.org/sql/#rank.rows), in which case you get to choose how the order (and rank) is determined.

Answer (score 0):

I've mixing session/@ variables and aggregation can be a bit unreliable, but you could simply try changing the order of your select expressions to 
`student_id, @cur:=SUM(total_marks), @curRank := IF(@prev= @cur, @curRank, @curRank + 1 ) AS classPosition, @prev:=@cur`

If this doesn't help, I'd suggest separating your aggregation and ranking. Actually, you're already summing in the subquery, so I am not quite sure why you're not just including the sum in the results from `n`.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT @curRank := IF(@prev= @cur, @curRank, @curRank + 1 ) AS classPosition, student_id, @prev:=@cur, @cur:=overall
FROM (SELECT m.*, SUM(total_marks) AS overall
    FROM marks m
    WHERE classform_name = ? AND term = ? AND academic_year = ? 
    GROUP BY student_id
    ORDER BY overall DESC
) AS n 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT  @curRank := 0, @prev:=NULL, @cur:=NULL ) AS q 
) AS completeRankings 
WHERE student_id = ?
```

Actually, your original query should've had other issues anyway. `n` would have only included a single random `total_marks` value for each student_id; making the outer SUM kind of pointless.

Edit -  This should allow position progression to "skip" later positions according to ties:

`SELECT @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS counter, @prevRank := IF(@prev=@cur, @prevRank, @curRank) AS classPosition`

... to omit `counter` from the final results, you'll have to expand out the `*` explicitly.

Comment: I tried your code ... Seems to work... Buh there were 3 ties.. on the 3rd, 4th & 5th but
The results was 123445 instead of 123336..

Comment: If you want positions to progress like that, you may need to keep an extra session variable `@prevRank` that only updates to the `@curRank` when `@prev != @cur`; you'll still need to update `@curRank` every row though. (See edit)

Answer (score -1):

Ranks are a real pain in MySQL.

If you want the rank for a single student with these conditions, I would recommend:

```
SELECT 1 + COUNT(*)
FROM marks m
WHERE m.classform_name = ? AND m.term = ? AND m.academic_year = ? AND
      m.total_marks >= (SELECT m2.total_marks
                        FROM marks m2
                        WHERE m2.classform_name = m.classform_name AND
                              m2.term = m.term
                              m2.academic_year = m.academic_year
                              m2.student_id = ?
                       );;
```

Comment: This doesn't works with group by clauses!